# Problem with start my Kubuntu on dell

Tags: kubuntu, 17.10, screen, login-screen

When I start my computer and decrypted SSD my Kubuntu displays a black screen with a flashing dash ( - ). I can't move on and work on OS. After several attempts, the login screen turns on.

I have Kubuntu 17.10, 16 gb RAM, Intel Core i7 and IntelUHD (Dell XPS).

Have any ideas?

Comment: XPS comes with high-end Nvidia graphics. You need `nomodeset` until you install Nvidia drivers.

Comment: What's the model number of your XPS? (I also have one) are you using an external monitor by any chance?

Comment: I have Dell XPS 13  9360 with Intel - not nvidia via a built-in monitor. Now I install ubuntu 17.10 and I have the same problem...